# Macro - maintain paste link if new row is added to master spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a master spreadsheet that has a portion of data (say columns a to e) that paste links to a report. Each row paste links to its own report. If I add a new row to the master spreadsheet I now have the wrong data linking into my reports.

I know if I have the reports open when a change is made to the master it will update the reports. However, with the number of reports I will soon have this will no longer be practical. Is there a macro or formula that can be added to maintain the correct data link?

Comment: Consider posting this on Stackoverflow for quicker response.